# /bin/bash How to interact with python virtualenv?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python

Using purely bash scripting (unless there is a good reason to use sh instead), how can one interact with the python virtualenv?

I am able to start python's virtualenv and keep a log file (which is what I currently need) as follows:

```
script -f -c python "/home/John/Desktop/python.log"
```

How can I now execute commands in the virtual environment from my script?

I tried naive approaches like this one inside my script:

```
"print('test123')">>python
```

But that obviously didn't work.

For people who are unfamiliar with Python:
Note that `print()` is a python function.
If I were to start the virtualenv manually and type `print("test123")` it would print inside the virtual environment (and my log file) `test123`.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem your `"print('test123')">>python` line is that it would, in theory, open a new python environment each time you did something like that. You would somehow have to direct to the same process using PIDs. I think you may also be confused as to what virtual environments are as running `python` will not create one or open one up.

Comment: One other question, why not simply write a Python script with the print statement in it, and then run the script?

Comment: To run a single line of Python code directly from Bash, you can do `python -c 'print("something")'`, but I am not sure if that is what you really want...

Comment: Use the full path to the Python executable in the virtual environment: `$HOME/my_virtualenv/bin/python -c "print('test123')"`